# Can't set size of size of element in html code—only through stylesheet

Tags: html, css

sorry if this has been answered before, but I haven't been able to find it anywhere.

I am trying to create a sort of thumbnail gallery but I am having trouble setting the width and heights of elements in the html code. For some reason it works if I set the size in the stylesheet, but not in the code itself. I have been trying to figure this out all night and it's driving me nuts. I'm hoping it's something simple that I am misunderstanding. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here's a link to a sample:

http://jsfiddle.net/4gupR/1/

CSS

```
.box {
display: block;
float: left;
margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
}
figure {
position: relative;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
display: block;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="box">
<figure width="800" height="800">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300">
</figure>
<figcaption>Caption</figcaption>
</div>
```

Just to clarify, it is important that I do this through the html code, and also, I need to set the size, and not just use margin, or padding…

As always, thanks so much for any help you can offer!

Comment: Your fiddle seems to be working, but I am worried about the `figure` element in non-HTML5 browsers...are you using a modern browser? And are you opening the HTML page code with `<!DOCTYPE html>`?

Comment: Not sure why you _need_ to set the sizes in the HTML code, but you could set the size on the image element, as in http://jsfiddle.net/4gupR/3/

Comment: thats because `<figure>` is `html5` and doesn't support `width` and `height` attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to use inline styles, you have to use the "style" attribute.

```
<div style="property: value;">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bZkYS/1/

Comment: Thanks so much! I could've sworn I tried that earlier—I must have made a mistake somewhere. Seems to have done the trick though, thank you so much!

Comment: Is there a short answer you could give me why it only works through CSS and not in the width/height html code? Just for future reference… Much appreciated!!!!

Comment: It does work. I took your code and added a 20 px width and red outline in the HTML and it works fine. See the fiddle...   http://jsfiddle.net/GutaJ/

Answer (score 0):

The attributes should go on the `img` tag, not the `figure` tag.

```
<figure>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300" width="400" height="300">
</figure>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, everyone. Let me just add some info to clarify a bit. I am building a site using Kirby (getkirby.com) for the CMS. In this section, I have a loop that adds images to each page. I wanted to use PHP to call the images' height and width, and set their containing divs' sizes to be squares, the size of the larger dimension. So in other words, if an image is 200x400 px, it will be inside a div that is 400x400 px. A 600x200 px image would be in a div that's 600x600 px. In this case, I want to keep the images at actual size and not resize them.

Comment: Also, I definitely don't have to use `figure` in this case. I tried it in a regular div, but it didn't help…

Answer (score 0):

Most html elements don't support *width* and *height* as attributes, but you *can* still set their width and height via CSS either in your stylesheet or directly in the html in a style attribute:

```
<figure style="width : 800px; height : 800px;">
```

(You seem to be already setting *display:block* in your stylesheet.)

Having said that, img elements actually do allow width and height attributes, so you could set them on your img.